# TTS Engine Post to Speech doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress as CMS and i installed the TTS Engine Post to Speech plugin. It is working fine for the first 15 posts, but when i load new posts without refreshing the page it doesn't work for the newly loaded posts.

I suspect that the script from the plugin needs to be reloaded again in order to work. Does anyone have this same problem and if nobody has it how can i at least reload the same script from the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a PHP Plugin, you can't reload it without refreshing. PHP runs at server side.

However, you can examine the code of the plugin, understand how it works and make an AJAX call to a webpage that will load the plugin and return speech file (or however it works..) and load it to the page.

Bottom line, you won't be able to do it without some custom coding. (assuming you talked about [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tts-engine-post-to-speech/) plugin, as it's documentation doesn't state anything about ajax reloading.